# Why does React Router changes the URL but the component doesn't get rendered when I click the LOGIN button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

**What I'm trying to do:** I'm trying to have the `LOGIN`UI component redirect the user to another page, with only login component on the page.

**Problem is:** When I click the LOGIN button the router changes to /login at the end (url) but it doesn't render the LoginForm component.

**Question:** Why is React Router url gets changed but the component doesn't get rendered when I click the LOGIN button? And How can i make it work?

All files below are in the src folder. [See file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj4fi.png)

Files below:

NavBar.js

```
import "./App.css";
import bag from "./bag.svg";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
function SearchBar() {
  return <input type="text" placeholder="SEARCH"></input>;
}
// this is the login UI 

function Login() {
  return <div>LOG IN</div>;
}

function Help() {
  return <div> HELP</div>;
}

function Cart() {
  return <img className="bag" src={bag} alt="shopping bag" />;
}

export default function NavBar() {
  return (
    <nav className="navBar">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <SearchBar />
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/LoginForm">
            <Login />
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Help />
        </li>
        <li>
          <Cart />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

LoginForm.js

```
export default function LoginForm() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>Hello</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import LoginForm from "./LoginForm.js";
import NavBar from "./NavBar.js";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        {/* <Route path="/" component={App} exact /> */}
        <Route path={"/LoginForm"} component={LoginForm} exact />
      </Routes>
      <NavBar />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import Slider from "./carousel.js";
import App from "./App.js";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import Props from "./hamburgerMenu.js";
import NavBar from "./NavBar.js";
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Props />
    <App />
    <NavBar />
    <Slider />
  </React.StrictMode>
);


reportWebVitals();
```

**I've tried:** I tried changing the path syntax  `<Route path={"/LoginForm"} component={LoginForm} exact />` to not have curly braces, put slash at the end of the component, put it in brackets.. etc. I've been looking at this for over three hours now and it's too hard to find a question that solves the same issue.

Per this question [react-router Link changes url but Route component doesn't render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59825252/react-router-link-changes-url-but-route-component-doesnt-render),
I've tried putting in the `exact` keyword but this didn't change anything for me.

[How to transfer code from codesandbox to Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67893687/how-to-transfer-code-from-codesandbox-to-visual-studio-code)
Removing StrictMode didn't work.

**I expected:** it to render the LoginForm component when LOGIN ui button is clicked.